# Recharts: how to set active dot?

Tags: recharts

On Recharts LineChart, I need to set the active dot from outside when some user event has accord.

I try to get inspired from [synchronizedLineChart example](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/SynchronizedLineChart) and to use `graphRef.current.triggerSyncEvent({activeCoordinate: {x: 251.1731843575419, y: 291}})` but it didn't work at all.

Is anyone try this before?